# DBeaver how to get back results window

Tags: windows-10, dbeaver

DBeaver used to be able to show SQL scripts in the top window and results in the bottom window on the same screen.  But now it won't show results at all.  How do I get results to show at the bottom of the screen with scripts at the top?

I've searched the Web but couldn't find any answers.  Thanks.

Environment:
Windows 10
DBeaver 6.1.5

Comment: Please post the screenshot if you can.

Answer (score 14):

Is it possible you have inadvetantly collapsed the results panel?

If so, you may see a small grey triangle / 'up-arrow' just above the status bar at the bottom of the query window.  Hovering your mouse pointer over the triangle / up-arrow icon shows the tool-tip 'Restore':

[image: Hovering your mouse pointer over the triangle / up-arrow icon shows the tool-tip 'Restore']

If you don't see that, perhaps try to post a screenshot of what you are seeing?

Comment: Thanks Nij. I don't see the restore triangle and I'm not sure how to post the screenshot here.

Comment: Sorry @LeoJones I don't know what else to suggest. For what its worth, there are some things about DBeaver that are baffling me about window management too... but it is a very powerful tool if you can get past this issue.

Comment: wasted 1 hour on this. thanks

Comment: Oh, the arrow is super tiny. It's in the middle of the screen on the  bar. If you manage to do the opposite and see only the results, but not the query, it appears on the top.

Comment: The triangles are on top of the results window, on the middle of the results panel.